I can't make my previous button work on an embed message (DISCORD.JS V14)
So I am trying to make a bot for discord, to see cards from the One Piece TCG.
For now, I can show a card with his ID, and I'm trying to make it work with an array. So actually, my "next" button is working pretty fine, I didn't see any problem. But when I click on my "previous" button, suddenly I got an error in my discord client "Interaction failure" (translated from french).
Therefore, in my code I can clearly see the right embed from the array with the index.
Here is my code :
const execute = async (interaction, pool) => {
    let cardName = "%" + interaction.options.getString("name") + "%"
    cardName = "%Luffy%"
    try {
        connection = await pool.getConnection();
        const [rows] = await connection.query('SELECT * FROM carte WHERE nom LIKE ?', [cardName]);

        const embeds = await Promise.all(rows.map(createCardEmbed)); // Créer tous les Embeds

        let currentIndex = 0; // Index pour suivre la carte actuellement affichés

        // Fonction pour créer les boutons de navigation
        const createActionRow = () => {
            return new ActionRowBuilder()
                .addComponents(
                    new ButtonBuilder()
                        .setCustomId('previous')
                        .setLabel('Previous Card')
                        .setStyle(ButtonStyle.Primary)
                        .setDisabled(currentIndex === 0), // Désactiver le bouton précédent si c'est la première carte
                    new ButtonBuilder()
                        .setCustomId('next')
                        .setLabel('Next Card')
                        .setStyle(ButtonStyle.Primary)
                        .setDisabled(currentIndex === embeds.length - 1) // Désactiver le bouton suivant si c'est la dernière carte
                );
        };

        // Envoyer le premier embed avec les boutons
        const message = await interaction.reply({
            ...embeds[currentIndex], // Envoie le premier embed
            components: [createActionRow()],
            fetchReply: true
        });

        // Collecteur de boutons pour naviguer entre les cartes
        const filter = i => i.customId === 'next' || i.customId === 'previous';
        const ClicOnPreviousOrNextButton = message.createMessageComponentCollector({ filter, time: 60000 });

        ClicOnPreviousOrNextButton.on('collect', async interaction => {
                if (interaction.customId === 'next' && currentIndex < embeds.length - 1) {
                    currentIndex++;
                } else if (interaction.customId === 'previous' && currentIndex > 0) {
                    currentIndex--;
                }

                await interaction.update({
                    ...embeds[currentIndex],
                    components: [createActionRow()]
                });
        });
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error)
        await interaction.reply('Error while getting the card');
    } finally {
        if (connection) connection.release();
    }
}

I tried several options that I saw on internet, or even with chatGPT (like to "defer" the interaction or all things like that) but no one was working.
I also tried to debug, but I couldn't achieve to find the problem
